# How to make fastcgi_pass uses localhost:port

Tags: nginx

This may not come across correctly as I want to do, please bear with me.

I have an ubuntu server running php 7.2 with nginx. We have a reverse proxy setup so the laravel server uses internal IP (AWS). The installation works but we need to modify the routing.

For laravel, all routes start with `/api/`. Our reverse proxy forwards traffic, `/v2/api/` to the private ip laravel server. That works but we get `404`. The laravel server access logs show `/v2/api` not found. Great. I need to make few changes. I need to route `/v2/api/` to `/api/`. How? The setup:

```
server_name <private-ip-address>;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location /v2/api/ {
  # proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/$2;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

For what I want to do, could  change `fastcgi_pass` to use `localhost:9000`? Port `9000` is not in use. Then use `proxy_pass` as above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to mix up two **nginx** directives: `fastcgi_pass` and `proxy_pass`:

- `fastcgi_pass` instructs **nginx** to execute a CGI script (PHP in your case) using the [FastCGI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).
- `proxy_pass` sends an HTTP request to another web server and returns it as if it was coming from the `server_name` domain.

You can serve static content with `proxy_pass`, but not with `fastcgi_pass`.

Coming back to your configuration, you need to set `server_name` to the domain name under which **nginx** will be accessible.

In your current configuration all request URIs ending with `.php`, except those starting with `/v2/api` will execute scripts on the **nginx** host. You probably don't want to change the `fastcgi_pass` directive argument to `localhost:9000`, since the Unix socket `run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` is faster.

Regarding the request URIs starting with `/v2/api/` you have two options:

- you can change the `proxy_pass` instruction to:

  ```
  proxy_pass http://<laravel_server>:<laravel_http_port>/api/
  ```

  in which case **nginx** will fetch `/v2/api/whatever` from `http://<laravel_server>:<laravel_http_port>/api/whatever` using HTTP.
- or if the **Laravel** server does not server any static content, you can run **PHP-FPM** on a TCP/IP socket (let's say 9000) and use

  ```
  fastcgi_pass <laravel_server>:9000
  ```

and add the [FastCGI Params](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) to reflect the **Laravel** server directory structure.

Comment: Thank you for this vast amout of information